# Asymptotic formula for the $L^2$ norm of a periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open and bounded set and $u^\varepsilon : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ an $\varepsilon$-periodic function, i.e. $$ u(x + \tau) = u(x) \quad \text{for all } \tau \in \varepsilon \mathbb{Z}^n. $$
Let $Q(0, \varepsilon)$ be the cube centered at $0$ with side length $2\varepsilon$. Assume $$ \frac{1}{\varepsilon^n} \int_{Q(0, \varepsilon)} |u^\varepsilon|^2 \, dx \to I$$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. Is it true that $$ \int_{\Omega} |u^\varepsilon|^2 \, dx \to \frac{|\Omega|}{2^n} I? $$

Clearly, the number of non-overlapping cubes of side length $2\varepsilon$ contained in $\Omega$ is asymptotically equal to $|\Omega|/(2\varepsilon)^n$ so that $$ \int_{\Omega} |u^\varepsilon|^2 \, dx \approx \frac{|\Omega|}{(2\varepsilon)^n} \int_{Q(0, \varepsilon)} |u^\varepsilon|^2 \, dx $$ However, I don't think this is enough to prove the claim since $|u^\varepsilon|^2$ might have a big integral on the small subset of $\Omega$ not covered by the cubes. I would appreciate any help.

Edit: The claim is made in the paper "A Strange Term Coming from Nowhere" which can be found [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-97184-1_4) (page 56). There a function $w^\varepsilon$ is defined on $Q(0, \varepsilon)$ as follows: For $x$ in the annulus $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : a^\varepsilon < x < \varepsilon \}$ set $$ w^\varepsilon(x) = \frac{(a^\varepsilon)^{2 - n} - |x|^{2 - n}}{(a^\varepsilon)^{2 - n} - \varepsilon^{2 - n}}, $$  where $0 < a^\varepsilon < \varepsilon $. Otherwise set $w^\varepsilon(x) = 0$. Extend $w^\varepsilon$ periodically to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Take $u^\varepsilon = \nabla w^\varepsilon$.

Note that $u^\varepsilon$ is rotationally symmetric on $Q(0, \varepsilon)$ and $$ \int_{Q(0, \varepsilon)} |u^\varepsilon|^2 \, dx = \frac{\omega_n(n - 2)}{(a^\varepsilon)^{2 - n} - \varepsilon^{2 - n}}$$ where $\omega_n$ is the surface area of the $(n - 1)$-dimensional unit sphere. Finally, take $a^\varepsilon = C_0 \varepsilon^{n/(n -2)}$ for some constant $C_0$ and observe that $$ \frac{1}{\varepsilon^n} \int_{Q(0, \varepsilon)} |u^\varepsilon|^2 \, dx \to \omega_n(n - 2)C_0^{n - 2}.$$

Edit: Corrected the formula for $w^\varepsilon$.

Comment: Maybe you mean $u(x+\tau)=u(x)$ for all $\tau\in \varepsilon \mathbb Z^d$. That definition of periodicity I think implies that $u$ is constant

Comment: Also, can you please be more precise on what is the precise statement that you want to prove? Do you want to show that the ratio of the two quantities converges to $1$ for small $\varepsilon$? Do you want to show that, for $\varepsilon$ small enough, one quantity bounds the other up to multiplicative constants that do not depend on $\varepsilon$, $u^\varepsilon$? In that case, are the constants allowed to depend on $\Omega$? I ask because I doubt that the only dependence of the constants would be on $|\Omega|$.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Thanks for the comments. You are right about the definition of periodicity. I wrote this before I went to sleep, so I wasn't very careful. I fixed things now.

Comment: I guess you would need mild assumption on the regularity of the boundary in order to get the desired result. In fact, I think you are good if the boundary of your set is a null set.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven That would certainly work. I think it's sufficient to assume $|\partial \Omega| = 0$ but the paper I am reading makes no such assumption.

Comment: Could you also include the paper in question? It seems a bit magical to me that this should in such generality.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Sure, I added some more comments. In the paper they do in fact work with a concrete function but I didn't see any property of the function that would help the claim.

Comment: @GérardLetac $\Omega$ is open.

Comment: Thank you, it looks more clear. With such an explicit sequence the claim does not sound impossible. I don’t have a precise answer, but I would suggest you to show that the sequence $u^\varepsilon$ is uniformly integrable (say, on a cube containing $\Omega$). In that case, when you fill $\Omega$ with small cubes you cannot write explicitly the remaining part of $\Omega$, but you can definitely prove that it has small measure for small $\varepsilon$. Then you can use the uniform integrability of the $u^\varepsilon$ to show that the integral on such a region converges to zero.

Comment: See here for the definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability . I think this sequence is indeed uniformly integrable, since $u^\varepsilon$ looks roughly like a rescaled version of $u^1$. Once you do that, you also need to show that when you approximate any open, bounded set from inside with $\varepsilon$-cubes, the measure of the remaining region converges to zero as $\varepsilon\to 0$. But it looks like you already know how to do that.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili You were right. I knew I would be finished if I showed $|u^\varepsilon|^2$ was uniformly integrable but didn't think it would be easy to check. Turns out $|u^\varepsilon|^2$ is simply of the form $c^\varepsilon/|x|^{2n - 2}$ with $c^\varepsilon$ tending to $0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. Thanks!

Comment: That’s normal. I often avoid doing things by hand and ask people to save some time, but then I realize I could do that myself and I was simply afraid of going into details and making a mistake. Sometimes the proof you look for is simply very low level real analysis tailored to your explicit problem